# Google Play Licensing with API 23

Tags: android, android-studio, licensing

I have to implement Google Play Licensing in my App (target API 23). There is any problem with the fact that http Client is not yet supported in API 23? In which way do the checkAccess method a connection to Google Play?

Comment: Correction: http Client is no longer supported in API 23...

Comment: so your question is how to import http Client in api 23?

Comment: No, the question is if I can implement check licencensing procedure with API 23 taking into account that checkAccess method should use (?) http Client to exchange data with Google Play

Answer (score 0):

The only way I've found so far is to put this on LVL project, at gradle:

```
    android
    {
        useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
    }
```